# Centos navigate SFTP User to have access to specific directory

Tags: linux, centos, sftp, centos-7

I am trying to give user full access to specific directory.

I am using SFTP on Centos 7. I am creating new group and user

```
groupadd ftpusers
useradd -m newuser -s /sbin/nologin -g ftpusers

chown root "directory"
chmod 750 "directory"
```

My `sshd_config` contains:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group ftpaccess
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

No matter what directory I put it gives me access to Home.

How can I make access to specific directory?

Comment: Please, clarify what is the question here. You specify `chrootdirectory` so the user does not have access anywhere else. If you specify different directory, he will have access to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
ChrootDirectory %h
```

allows the access to the home directory of that user. If you want to give an access to different directory, just use

```
ChrootDirectory /full/path/to/directory
```

Comment: Hi, when I added directory as u suggested it wont connect the user.

Comment: It obviously needs to point to the directory you created (with full path) and all of the parents needs to be owned by root and not writable by any other user.